# Find the slope m of the curve $x + y^3(x)= 6$ at the point $(1, \sqrt[3]5)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, implicit-differentiation

When asking if y(x) is equal to the y value I'm told that " y(x) is the y value, but viewed as a function of x in this context, not as an independent variable."

What exactly does this mean? Should I replace with y(x) with 6−x or should I just differentiate the original function normally using implicit differentitation?

Comment: @dantopa: the $x$ is clearly not supposed to be in the exponent based on the original question.  It was a (to my mind strange) way of showing that $y$ depends on $x$ and we want the derivative of $y$.

Comment: @RossMillikan: Thanks for helping the OP, the readers, and me.

Answer (score 1):

Your function is $y=\sqrt[3]{6-x}$  You can differentiate that or you can implicitly differentiate the original equation getting $1+3y^2y'=0$  Since you know $y$ you can compute $y'$.

Comment: The function actually becomes $y=(6-x)^{\frac{1}{3x}}$, which might yield an  ugly derivative.

Comment: @GuilhermeK.Nakassima:  There was an incorrect edit of the title.

Comment: @RossMillikan I've retracted the comment.

Answer (score 0):

Implicitly differentiate your function, then insert the point coordinates $(x,y)=(1,\root3\of{5})$ into it.

Alternatively, you can just isolate $y$ and differentiate as usual.